# Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

i move my source window to ubuntu :

Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

this is my source thank you

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: Did you click the link? Sounds like they've just changed the way you download the pieces you need.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are a number of changes with express 4.x.  Like the error says, all of the middleware has been removed.

Update your package.json to include the "new" packages, a basic list can be found [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) and a full list [here](https://github.com/expressjs)

Using your code from above, you would just need the following:

```
// package.json
{
  "dependencies":
  {
    "express":"*",
    "body-parser":"*"
  }
}
```

Then update your source to reflect the new changes:

```
// app.js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Note that app.use(app.router) has been removed as well.

Comment: Wow! Thanks dude, you saved my time! :)
I'm a beginner to NodeJS even though I have been heard about it from its existence! :) And my code didn't run till I do the following!

1). updated the package to be defined the dependency of bodyParser!
2). declared the class reference to a variable(js object) as you have given in your list of Vars.
3). replaced the following line which was in my tutorial guided app,
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

with following:

    app.use(bodyParser());

Now my node server starts as it was! :)
Thanks for the help! It seems like the issue is new with Express 4.*

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  It's not really an issue, more of a feature :).  All of the middleware in express has been separated out into packages so that you can get only what you need and keep your code small and focused.  The problem is that all of the examples, books, and videos out there are about previous versions so will leave a bit of confusion for a while.  If you are learning and are going from tutorials you may also want to just stick with express 3.x by specifying the version in your package.json file.

Comment: :) Yup, sorry for that mistake it's not an issue with Express 4.*, but it's a feature for the future! :) Because, they have tried to improve it in the way you said, in much modular manner!
And I'm going through bit older tutorials which uses 3.x, but I tend to correct and update them by myself to be conform with Express 4.x and other middleware plugins! :) Becuase that way I can build for the newer platform! :) (Y)

Comment: I am just facing a similar issue right now. Where does the "extended: true" come from in the code above.

Comment: The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded. For more information, please see the qs library.


From https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Answer (score 3):

if some middleware is not bundled with express then dont use express keyword while using them..

instead of this -

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

write this -

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Comment: There is no difference between two statements. :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was exporting a package that i didn't install i.e express package. after installing the package my issue went away. the middleware i was using is

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Check your package.json file whether you installed the package or not. If it is not installed then you might be getting same error.